# BigQuery: Best way to ORDER BY an arbitrary GROUP BY expression?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In the below query, I want to group all orders by the concatenation of firstname and lastname, and order the result set by that concatenation.  However, BigQuery returns the following error for the query:

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(o.ORDERID)
FROM EMPLOYEES e
INNER JOIN ORDERS o ON e.EMPLOYEEID = o.EMPLOYEEID
GROUP BY CONCAT(e.FIRSTNAME, ' ', e.LASTNAME)
ORDER BY CONCAT(e.FIRSTNAME, ' ', e.LASTNAME)
```

> ORDER BY clause expression references column [column_name] which is neither grouped nor aggregated

I can fix this by wrapping the `ORDER BY` clause in `ANY_VALUE`:

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(o.ORDERID)
FROM EMPLOYEES e
INNER JOIN ORDERS o ON e.EMPLOYEEID = o.EMPLOYEEID
GROUP BY CONCAT(e.FIRSTNAME, ' ', e.LASTNAME)
ORDER BY ANY_VALUE(CONCAT(e.FIRSTNAME, ' ', e.LASTNAME))
```

Is this best practice? Is there a more canonical way to do this for arbitrary `GROUP BY` expressions?  Other DBMS, including MySQL, SQLServer, Postgres, etc. handle the first query without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use numbers or references.  Also, you can have the `GROUP BY` key in the `SELECT`.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.FIRSTNAME, ' ', e.LASTNAME) as fullname
       COUNT(o.ORDERID)
FROM EMPLOYEES e INNER JOIN
     ORDERS o
     ON e.EMPLOYEEID = o.EMPLOYEEID
GROUP BY fullname
ORDER BY fullname;
```

You can also write the last two lines as:

```
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the expression to the SELECT clause makes sense, but then that's selecting data I don't necessarily want. Can you describe what you mean by using "numbers or references?"

Comment: @PeterFernandes . . . You already *have* the expression in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Good observation, sorry for that oversight. I didn't mean to include it in the `SELECT` in the example (I'm going to edit it out now).

Comment: @PeterFernandes . . . This answers the question you asked here.  Changing the question invalidates the answer.  It is better to ask a *new* question.

Comment: New question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67595991/976126