# Computed group by does not work when used with order by in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, sql-order-by

This query works fine:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE(start_date),
  COUNT(DISTINCT bike_id)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data`.london_bicycles.cycle_hire
GROUP BY
  DATE(start_date);
```

and outputs 892 rows. But when I add an ORDER BY to it, like so:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE(start_date),
  COUNT(DISTINCT bike_id)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data`.london_bicycles.cycle_hire
GROUP BY
  DATE(start_date)
ORDER BY DATE(start_date) DESC;
```

then it gives me an error:

```
ORDER BY clause expression references column start_date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [7:33]
```

If I use the column aliases, then it works fine:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE(start_date) AS the_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT bike_id)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data`.london_bicycles.cycle_hire
GROUP BY
  the_date
ORDER BY
  the_date DESC;
```

I want to understand why this behavior exists. How does the SQL engine work, that it is able to run the group by clause, but then is not able to run the same query with an additional ordering clause?

I understand the execution order is: from, where, group by, having, select, order by, limit. But I am not able to relate this to the error above.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595222/bigquery-best-way-to-order-by-an-arbitrary-group-by-expression) and [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595991/bigquery-best-way-to-order-by-an-arbitrary-group-by-expression-when-that-expres), but this just explains how to fix the error. But I want to understand why this error happens in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let start with following example, where the `DATE(start_date)` is used twice.

```
SELECT
  DATE(start_date) AS the_date,
  DATE(start_date) AS also_the_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT bike_id)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data`.london_bicycles.cycle_hire
GROUP BY
  the_date, also_the_date
ORDER BY
  the_date DESC;
```

If in the `GROUP BY` the column `also_the_date` is missing, an error is raised. The query does not know, that the result of both function is the same.

The same is true, if a function of a column is used in the `ORDER BY`.